# Stata interaction variable previous year

Tags: stata, interaction

I'm using Stata and my panel data set is in the following format:

| year | ID | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 100 | . |
| 2001 | 1 | 200 | 0.2 |
| 2002 | 1 | 300 | 0.3 |
| 2000 | 2 | 500 | . |
| 2001 | 2 | 300 | 0.4 |
| 2002 | 2 | 400 | 0.1 |

I would like to create an interaction variable between var2 and var1 where the interaction of var2 with var1 is always based on the previous year. In other words, var2 in 2001 should interact with var1 from 2000. Hence, the output should look like this:

| year | ID | var1 | var2 | var1Xvar2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 100 | . | . |
| 2001 | 1 | 200 | 0.2 | 20 |
| 2002 | 1 | 300 | 0.3 | 60 |
| 2000 | 2 | 500 | . | . |
| 2001 | 2 | 300 | 0.4 | 20 |
| 2002 | 2 | 400 | 0.1 | 30 |

How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Nick Cox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989439/stata-interaction-variable-previous-year/65989688?noredirect=1#comment116674882_65989688), here is an updated answer to your problem. The update uses the lag operator `L1.var1`, which is greatly superior relative to `var1[_n-1]` when creating lagged variables. It prevents the code from taking observations from a different panel (in this case, different `year`.)

```
clear all
input year  ID  var1    var2
2000    1   100 .
2001    1   200 0.2
2002    1   300 0.3
2000    2   500 .
2001    2   300 0.4
2002    2   400 0.1

end
// Declare data to be time series
tsset ID year
// Use Lag operator on var1 (for details see: help tsvarlist)
gen wanted  = L1.var1 * var2

list

/*   +----------------------------------+
     | year   ID   var1   var2   wanted |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 2000    1    100      .        . |
  2. | 2001    1    200     .2       20 |
  3. | 2002    1    300     .3       60 |
  4. | 2000    2    500      .        . |
  5. | 2001    2    300     .4      200 |
     |----------------------------------|
  6. | 2002    2    400     .1       30 |
     +----------------------------------+ */
```

Comment: This works in practice, at least in the data example, because `var2` is missing for the first observation for each panel. In principle it is greatly preferable to go `tsset ID year` and then `gen wanted  = L1.var1 * var2`. What is essential is to avoid use of any previous observation in the dataset that is for a different panel.

Comment: You are right, @NickCox, I updated the answer based on your comment. Thank you.